# openssl(1.1.0.b) is not support secp256r1?(openssl ecparam - list_curves)

Tags: openssl

my server and client need secp256r1 in handshake, but openssl seems like do not support secp256r1.

when I command openssl ecparam -list_curves, i couldn't see secp256r1

i used openssl 1.1.0b. I wonder openssl not support secp256r1?

Comment: You may not see it in the list of curves, but OpenSSL recognizes it. Try `grep -IR secp256r1 apps/` (from the OpenSSL source directory) or visit [`apps/ecparams.c : 220`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ecparam.c#L221).

Comment: i checked it up thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The OpenSSL supports secp256r1, it is just called prime256v1.
Have a look at the section 2.1.1.1 in [RFC 5480](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt).

> -- Note that in [PKI-ALG] the secp192r1 curve was referred to as
>
> -- prime192v1 and the secp256r1 curve was referred to as
>
> -- prime256v1.

Comment: The names are from ANSI X9.62; not RFC 5480. The RFC likely cites ANSI. Also see the comments for [`ecparams.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ecparam.c#L221).